# Upload Youtube Video is successful but no video on youtube channel

Tags: node.js, video, youtube, google-api-nodejs-client

Last week I was able to upload a video on my youtube channel. Today I've tried doing the same thing without any success.

Code wise I'm not getting any errors whatsoever.

Here is the result for my

```
yt.videos.insert({/* video info here and media*/}, function(err, res){
  console.log(err);
  console.log(res);
});
```

---

For the `console.log(err)` I get "null"
and for the `console.log(res)` I get:

```
I20151130-14:25:26.474(1)? { kind: 'youtube#video',
I20151130-14:25:26.474(1)?   etag: '"mPrpS7Nrk6Ggi_P7VJ8-KsEOiIw/iM-gBcVX-kDvfZG6P8kQD4388vM"',
I20151130-14:25:26.475(1)?   id: 'Z2NpA49QxTg',
I20151130-14:25:26.475(1)?   snippet: 
I20151130-14:25:26.475(1)?    { publishedAt: '2015-11-30T13:25:06.000Z',
I20151130-14:25:26.475(1)?      channelId: 'UCXUwJ50BHxJV5NS5bQ4f8NA',
I20151130-14:25:26.475(1)?      title: 'foo',
I20151130-14:25:26.476(1)?      description: 'bar',
I20151130-14:25:26.476(1)?      thumbnails: { default: [Object], medium: [Object], high: [Object] },
I20151130-14:25:26.476(1)?      channelTitle: 'WebSurg Ircad',
I20151130-14:25:26.476(1)?      categoryId: '27',
I20151130-14:25:26.477(1)?      liveBroadcastContent: 'none',
I20151130-14:25:26.477(1)?      localized: { title: 'foo', description: 'bar' } },
I20151130-14:25:26.477(1)?   status: 
I20151130-14:25:26.477(1)?    { uploadStatus: 'uploaded',
I20151130-14:25:26.477(1)?      privacyStatus: 'private',
I20151130-14:25:26.478(1)?      license: 'youtube',
I20151130-14:25:26.478(1)?      embeddable: true,
I20151130-14:25:26.478(1)?      publicStatsViewable: true } }
```

---

I checked Google's Developers Console and this is the result:

[image: Google's Developpers Console]

It is in french, but it translates to: "Successful operations 2 100%" with no errors.

**Question:**

What am I doing wrong that may be causing this problem?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I'm facing a similar issue and getting downvotes for asking basically the same question as you.

Comment: @YuChen sorry it's been two years. I don't remember much on the subject. Good luck though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While asking this question, the problem solved itself. It sometimes takes longer than usual for the video to appear in your video list.

However, the previous two hours I had gotten the same result and the videos never appeared in my video list.